# Resolving 'ValueError: Unexpected end of file.' from scipy/wavfile/read

Tags: java, python, scipy, wav

I am splitting a stereo wav file in Java using iterative methods with the Java WavFile class. When I use a python to read the resulting mono wav file and out put the sample rate and data using the read method from scipy.io.wavfile I get an error:

'Value Error: Unexpected end of File.'

I do not get this error with other mono wav files I try, only those I have made with Java. Looking at other forum posts I know that it must have to do with how I am setting up the header information for the files, however, after trying altercations and reading API docs to ensure that my usage is correct, I am at a loss.

My Java Code

```
try {
            WavFile srcFile = WavFile.openWavFile(this.audioFile);

            long numFrames = srcFile.getNumFrames();
            long sampleRate = srcFile.getSampleRate(); 
            int channels = 2;
            int bitRate = 16;


            File[] files = new File[channels];
            WavFile[] wavFiles = new WavFile[channels];

            for (int i = 1; i < channels + 1; i++) {
                //Populates File Array
                files[i - 1] = new File("output" + i + ".WAV");
                wavFiles[i - 1] = WavFile.newWavFile(files[i - 1], 1, numFrames, bitRate, sampleRate);
            }

            int bufferLength = Math.toIntExact(numFrames);

            int[][] buffer = new int[channels][bufferLength];

            long frameCounter = 0;

            while (frameCounter < numFrames){
                srcFile.readFrames(buffer,bufferLength);

                for (int j = 0; j<channels;j++){
                    wavFiles[j].writeFrames(buffer[j],bufferLength);
                }

                frameCounter += bufferLength;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("WavFile failed to open source file: " + ex);
        }
```

The simple python code that extracts data from the wav file

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

fs, data = wav.read(file)

wav.close()
```

From my understanding the python code should have no problem reading the wav file no matter its source.

Comment: Can you link to one of the files generated by your Java code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this will work, but just as a suggestion, try putting your wav file through the following: `ffmpeg -i "orig.wav" -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 "ffmpeg.wav"`, then try running the python script on it again. Also, try creating a wav file with ffmpeg to see if that runs. This is just to rule out the possibility of a faulty install.

Comment: Here is a dropbox link. I hope that works. https://www.dropbox.com/s/leolwqmimiriqab/output1.WAV?dl=0

Comment: Using ffmpeg allowed the code to run. What does it do exactly? I will read into it tomorrow when I have time again. However, if you are willing to put it in your own words that would help.

Comment: I just needed close statements. ffmpeg made sure there were the amount of frames that the header information stated there would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java code never calls the `close()` method for `wavFiles[j]`.  According to http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html, the `close()` method "*must* be called once all samples have been written using the writeFrames methods. If not called, the wav file may be incomplete."

Comment: That is absolutely the issue. The python program can now run the wav files without having to use any third party software. Thank you for the input and link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you got incorrect data in the [head of wav file](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/). I'm pretty sure that the number of frames in the file is smaller than the actual one.

You can either try to find the source of the error in the Java code, or use a Python library that is more resilient to header errors, such as the built-in library `wave`:

```py
>>> import wave
>>> track = wave.open('output1.WAV', 'r')
>>> track.getnframes()
3417927
>>> track.readframes(10)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00'
```

And don't forget to do `track.close()` or to use a [with statement](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I will try using the more generic wav file reader. However, 3417927 is the number of frames that the original has as well. At least according to the methods that the java wav file class has.

Comment: @AndrewA. right, since `wave` counts the number of frames from the stream, not from the headers. I checked that wavfile works when adding a zero-padding of 3726 bytes to the file you provided, but I don't know where is the error in the Java code.

Comment: It was my lack of close statements. Other classes that I use don't require them so I forgot to add them in this method. This created an unfinished .wav file that didn't match the header data. Thank you, your information helped me confirm the closing issue.