# EOF in scipy.io.wavfile.read

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I was trying to get data of a wav file using scipy.io.wavfile.read but it always returns this error message: **ValueError: Unexpected end of file.**

I went through all the related questions on this site (I guess). But none of them worked. I have also tried writing filename as **r**'Mozart 40 Allegro.wav'.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

sample,data=scipy.io.wavfile.read('Mozart 40 Allegro.wav')
print(data)
```

***Note***: Others have mentioned that my wav file may be corrupt, so I downloaded a [sample wav file](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-wav-download/). And this was the result.  **WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
WavFileWarning)**

But is there any way to get the wav file I require which is not corrupt and doesn't give the second error message I mentioned?

Thank You

***Thanks***: Initially I used some online converter but they do a very bad job in keeping the file intact with the precise format, vlc can handle such errors but these can't. Always use sox to convert and other stuff and don't forget to include the required extra files (lame files) if you are working with mp3.

Comment: *"...  returns this error message: ValueError: Unexpected end of file."*  That means the file is probably corrupted.  How was the file created?

Comment: Here's a similar question where the problem was that the file was not created correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387983/resolving-valueerror-unexpected-end-of-file-from-scipy-wavfile-read

Comment: I downloaded it and converted into wav.

Comment: *How* did you convert it to wav?

Answer (score 1):

I have some similar problems with some files that aren't created with proper headers. To solved I first transformed the file from wav to wav with ffmeg. This creates the metadata for the  wav file.

Then the steps to follow should be more or less:

```
ffmpeg -i "Mozart 40 Allegro.wav" -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 "Mozart 40 Allegro_.wav"
```

And then the new created file should have the proper metadata. So now it should not raise the error when it is opened on python:

```
sample,data=scipy.io.wavfile.read('Mozart 40 Allegro_.wav')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore for spaces:

```
sample,data=scipy.io.wavfile.read('Mozart_40_Allegro.wav')
```

Try:

```
import soundfile as sf
audio = sf.read("file")
```

Comment: Didn't help Still the same thing.

Comment: Will I get the same result? Amplitudes?

Comment: I am having a really hard time to install that module even using anaconda. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: can you use pip?

Comment: @Karthik How have you been trying to install it?

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile

Comment: @Karthik or: conda install -c conda-forge soundfile